# Hamburger drop-down menu not working when page is in "mobile" size on desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my hamburger button isn't working when I minimize the page to mobile size. Everything else seems to flow correctly, I've checked numerous times on the code and it seems to be correct. At this point, I'm not sure whether it's the script codes I have down below which disables the drop-down menu or what?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gallery.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" date-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> IMAGES</a>
            </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1><span class="fas fa-camera-retro"></span> The Image Gallery</h1>
        <p>Wonderful pictures at your disposal!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6" >
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439524970634-649c37a69e5c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1450&h=825&fit=crop&s=bfda9916c885869b43b70738693428d9">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444090542259-0af8fa96557e?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1434543177303-ef2cc7707e0d?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1436262513933-a0b06755c784?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439396087961-98bc12c21176?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439694458393-78ecf14da7f9?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>  

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the head you link to https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css and at the bottom you link to https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Not sure what I was supposed to do, but I tried removing each link separately to see if the drop-down would work -- no luck.

Comment: Do you want to use BS 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

-> please update following code into your existing code.

-> must be same id name into button data-target name and collapse id name.

-> also add meta tag into head tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Image Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gallery.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> IMAGES</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1><span class="fas fa-camera-retro"></span> The Image Gallery</h1>
                <p>Wonderful pictures at your disposal!</p>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6" >
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg">
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435771112039-1e5b2bcad966?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442406964439-e46ab8eff7c4?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439524970634-649c37a69e5c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1450&h=825&fit=crop&s=bfda9916c885869b43b70738693428d9">
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444090542259-0af8fa96557e?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1434543177303-ef2cc7707e0d?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1436262513933-a0b06755c784?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439396087961-98bc12c21176?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439694458393-78ecf14da7f9?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=825&q=50&w=1450">
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>  

        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```